# Unable to upload video on youtube server through java web application via REST and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to upload video directly to youtube server through my web application.

My application is Java Web Application where back end is REST Services where as front end is in Angular Js(JavaScript Framework)

Task :
My Application provides facility to user to upload videos.
So maintain the videos at server side.

> I am thinking to upload it on Youtube Server so that it will be easy
>   to maintain from my side.

```
Question, is this Best Practice?
```

I have tried some solutions like directly upload video through javascript as youtube data api supports https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript.
Problem faced : Though I am storing the OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID in the frontend ,

> but it still ask user to login in Google account now the problem is
>   ,How an end user can login to my Google account?

Then I look into Google Server Account Facility , but i didn't get any concrete example.

> How can I upload videos to youtube server from backend or frontend but
>   without prompting end user to login?

Any example is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Proper authorization is needed when uploading videos to YouTube. The good thing is, [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) provides good documentation and samples on how to do this.

For code samples for authorizing users in JS, check out [this sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#authorizing_requests).

Since you're using Java for your server-side implementation, you can check out [this sample page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java) to check out how to upload videos.